# The relationship between Golbach's Conjecture and the Riemann Hypothesis

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, riemann-hypothesis, goldbachs-conjecture

My question pertains to two famous groups of related conjectures:

Goldbach's Conjecture (**GC**); Goldbach's Weak Conjecture (**GWC**); The Riemann Hypothesis (**RH**); The Generalized Riemann Hypothesis (**GRH**).

These two groups of conjectures both appear to be strong statements about the distribution of the prime numbers. Yet it is unclear to me if each provides independent information about the distribution of the primes.

If the two conjectures expressed the same underlying fact, we would expect a strong coupling between the conjectures, such as **GC** *if and only if* **RH**. Therefore, I am asking if someone would someone please take the time to review the state of the reseach on the  relationships between **GC**, **GWC**, **RH**, and **GRH**. References for any results mentioned would be much appreciated.

For my part, I've read that by assuming **GRH**, one can provide an asymptotic proof of **GWC**. This strikes me as a weak relationship, and I wonder if there are stronger results which make use of **RH** to prove **GC**.

In the other direction, I've heard one person claim, without references, that **GC** implies **RH**. The latter claim seems unlikely to me, but I'd like to find someone that can set the record straight.

*Note*: I am looking for relationships across the two conjectures. It is clear to me that **GC** implies **GWC**, and **GRH** implies **RH**.

Comment: A [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266899/why-the-riemann-hypothesis-doesnt-imply-goldbach). Also [here](http://modular.math.washington.edu/edu/2010/414/projects/dingman.pdf), page $8$, final paragraph. [This](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/GoldbachFinal.pdf) might also prove helpful.

Comment: Thank you. I've seen the first post, and I'll take a look at the second. Just to keep information in one place, an outline of an asymptotic proof of **GWC** assuming **GRH** can be found [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/era/1997-03-15/S1079-6762-97-00031-0/S1079-6762-97-00031-0.pdf). This reference was provided by one one of the posters from Lucian's first link.

Comment: The link I provided in the comment below outlines a proof strategy to "show that an averaged strong form of Goldbach’s conjecture is equivalent to the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis". It is the same link as Lucian's third link.

Comment: Lucian's second link provides a reference that **RH** implies **GH** asymptotically:  "In 1997, Deshouillers, Enger, te Riele and Zinoviev proved that the
generalized Riemann hypothesis implies Goldbach's strong conjecture [Borwein et al., 2008]"

Answer (score 2):

Here is a related question that addresses your concerns(see the answer):

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61842/about-goldbachs-conjecture/62109#62109

Comment: From that discussion, [here](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/GoldbachFinal.pdf) is a reference to a paper that claims to "*show that an averaged strong form of Goldbach’s conjecture is
equivalent to the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis*". It is not yet clear to me what an average strong form of **GC** is.