# What is the relationship between GRH and Goldbach Conjecture?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-hypothesis, goldbachs-conjecture

We know that we can prove weak Goldbach Conjecture (three prime theorem) if we assume GRH (Hardy-Littlewood had proved this).

Can we also prove strong Goldbach Conjecture if we assume GRH ?

Also, any results on reverse direction ?
If we assume Goldbach Conjecture holds true, can we get any results about GRH ?

Comment: Could you write what GRH stands for? I'm interested in number theory but I don't recognize the initials. Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Riemann_hypothesis

Comment: Under related, it appears the question has been asked: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671694/the-relationship-between-golbachs-conjecture-and-the-riemann-hypothesis?rq=1 The answer to that question points to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/61842/about-goldbachs-conjecture/62109#62109 in which the answer (not the question) discusses this a bit.