# Does the Riemann-Hypothesis imply the Twin-Prime-Conjecture?

Tags: number-theory, riemann-hypothesis, twin-primes

The Riemann hypothesis (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis)
is one of the most important conjectures in number theory. I read that the
Riemann hypothesis implies the Goldbach Conjecture and would allow much
better estimates for the prime-counting function.

What about the Twin-Prime-Conjecture ?

Would it follow from the Riemann-hypothesis ?

Comment: The *generalized* Riemann hypothesis implies Goldbach's weak conjecture. The other claim need not be true.

Comment: So, the Riemann hypothesis does NOT necessarily imply the (Strong) Goldbach conjecture ?

Comment: No, RH for the zeta function alone is not enough.

Comment: Then, I must have misunderstood something.

Comment: I do not remember, where I read this, but I thought I read it several times. Either I overlooked the words "generalized" and "weak", or the author(s) forgot then.

Comment: This link : http://primes.utm.edu/glossary/xpage/goldbachconjecture.html claims that the Riemann-hypothesis (not generalized) implies the ODD Goldbach conjecture. Is this true, or do we need the generalized version even for the weak Goldbach conjecture ?

Comment: @Peter: Odd Goldbach has been a theorem of Helfgott since 2013. Unconditionally (not depending on RH or GRH).

Comment: If the generalized Riemann-hypothesis is true, would this imply the strong goldbach-conjecture ?

Comment: Again no, only the weak Goldbach conjecture would follow, see this MSE questions [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671694/the-relationship-between-golbachs-conjecture-and-the-riemann-hypothesis), and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266899/why-the-riemann-hypothesis-doesnt-imply-goldbach).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say no. Many authors state that RH would tell us nothing more (about prime gaps) than $p_{n+1}-p_n \in \text{O}(\sqrt{p_n}\log p_n)$, which obviously doesn't imply TPC, and so it should not be unsafe to say RH doesn't imply TPC.

Answer (score 4):

I think that RH does not imply the twin prime conjecture. A couple of quotations from Dan Goldston in his paper [here](http://www.math.sjsu.edu/~goldston/twinprimes.pdf) are in favour of this opinion:

"While the Riemann Hypothesis is decisive in determining the distribution of primes, it seems to be of little help with regard to twin primes."

"The conjecture that the distribution of twin primes satisfies a Riemann Hypothesis type error term is well supported empirically, but I think this might be a problem that survives the current millennium."

Comment: Here's a problem: Suppose someone using techniques not remotely related to Riemann's $\zeta$ function proves the twin prime conjecture.  Then the statement "If R.H. then twinprimeconjecture" is (vacuously) true.  Can one then PROVE that in some sense R.H. does not imply the twin prime conjecture?  Maybe one could speak of some nonstandard models in which R.H. is true and the twin prime conjecture is false, and that would show the impossibility of certain kinds of proofs that T.P.C. follows from R.H.  I suspect that's not easy. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Michael Hardy: Implication and entailment are not the same thing. Entailment is a much stronger condition, and is often what is really meant by implication. For example, “2 + 2 = 5” implies “The moon is made of green cheese.”, but does not entail it.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde: Memevidentas, ke la angla ne estas via gepatra lingvo.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, as I recently learned from a [popular Mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397585/siegel-zeros-and-other-illusory-worlds-building-theories-around-hypotheses-be), if the <s>RH</s> GRH is **false** in a specific way *(it has [Siegel zeros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel_zero))*, that would [imply the Twin Prime conjecture is **true**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel_zero#Infinitude_of_twin_primes) (!!)

Comment: RH has nothing to do with Siegel zeroes, it is GRH that does and you need a lot of Siegel zeroes to get the Twin Prime conjecture, but yes that is a cool result

Comment: @Conrad: Interesting. So it's possible for there to be enough Siegel zeros to cause the Twin Prime conjecture to be true, _and_ for the non-general RH to be true?

Comment: technically yes, but highly unlikely since if RH is true there will be a reason for that and the same reason will most likely work for GRH